# Is it possible to make a specific element not cause scroll bars in it's parent?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a container div, and numerous elements inside of it (i.e. spans, img, divs, etc).

I would like the container div to scroll naturally if its content becomes too large. However, there is ONE div inside of the container div that I would like to NOT cause the container to scroll if it becomes too large.

Not even sure if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

PS. No jQuery please! :)

Comment: Do you have some code to show or a fiddle?

Comment: I'll see what I can do. This is part of a larger application that is extraordinarily complex, so hopefully other styles aren't getting in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say this "*ONE div inside of the container div that I would like to NOT cause the container to scroll if it becomes too large.*" is `div#inner`. You can set a `max-width` or `max-height` to it and make it `overflow:hidden` so once it reaches the max size, it will stop growing and hide the overflowing inner content.

Comment: Creative idea. However, the innerdiv doesn't grow. Its getting repositioned.

Comment: @thepriebe if you could show the code in a fiddle I will try to give you a more precise answer mate

Comment: Not sure why people are deleting answers. There was some good stuff here. One of which was the exact solution I required. Only can't give him the credit. Yours, on the other hand is very close, and as you're the only one left You get the credit. :D

Also, thanks a lot for your help. You got me thinking in the right direction, so to speak, which led to the solution.

Comment: Great! Im glad it was of some help to you nonetheless.

Comment: +Tyler Biscoe: So... what was the solution? I'm looking for it too. (You can create your own answer, by the way. I'm sure blackpla9ue wouldn't mind.)

Comment: Please create an answer.